# Why Input having blank Values? While Printing HTML

Tags: jquery, html, forms

This is my html

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
<div id="jj">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I have to send **HTML** of **jj** id div to another page for Create Pdf I am using https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

My jquery code is :

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
 //$('#textarea').val($('#jj').html());
 console.log($('#jj').html());
 return false;
 });
```

Every time when i fill up input and click on submit. Console having html of blank input values. **Why?????** I want values of input also.

Console Output:

```
<input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3b5L/)

Comment: Because the attribute `value` does not change when the property value changes.

Comment: Changing the value of an input does not change the underlying HTML. What can't you just submit the form like normal? Or get the `value` (*property* not *attribute*) of each input and send that somewhere via AJAX?

Comment: any solution??? i want to send html to create pdf using dompdf

Comment: @Jamm - Send the values to the server and create the appropriate HTML for your PDF on the server.

Comment: I want to send html to create Pdf and i m using https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value of an input does not change the underlying HTML. But you can do it with jQuery.

Just add:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

**Explanation:**

Every time you write something in your `input` elements this code is changing your underlying HTML. It set the `value` attribute to the string you just wrote.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3b5L/4/)

**EDIT**

As Batu Zet pointed out it doesnt work on copy/paste through mouse. So you better use this code:

```
$('input').on("input", function() {

   $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/z3b5L/7/)

Comment: Awesome Please give explanation.

Comment: Just asking no offense. How about copy/paste through mouse?

Comment: @laaposto - you may be better with `blur()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try, You will get `JavaScript` object of all `inputs` with their corresponding Values

```
$(function(){

$('#form').submit(function(){
 //$('#textarea').val($('#jj').html());
 console.log($('#jj input ').clone().find("input").val("").end());
 return false;
 });

});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/z3b5L/3/)</kbd>

**Updated Edit 1**

```
$(function(){

    $('#form').submit(function(){

    $( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
    })

     console.log($('#jj').html());
     return false;
     });

    });
```

<kbd>[**NEW Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/z3b5L/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for bothering I want html? Pdf require html

Comment: Why `clone()`? No need to copy an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

$('#form').submit(function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("jj");
  var inputArr = div.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++)
    inputArr[i].setAttribute("value",inputArr[i].value);

   //$('#textarea').val($('#jj').html());
  console.log($('#jj').html());
  return false;
  });

});
```